# How to run recent project or solution as administrator on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, window, visual-studio-2015

From this article : 
[How to Run Visual Studio as Administrator by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default)

and 
[Can you force Visual Studio to always run as an Administrator in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)

and 
[Visual Studio Version Selector Doesn't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304425/visual-studio-version-selector-doesnt-open)

I try to set ***devenv.exe*** and ***VSLauncher.exe*** to always run as admin

---

Yes, when I open by shortcut -> it works!

[image]

result...

[image]

---

Or open project&solution directly -> it works!

[image]

result...

[image]

---

**########################## Question ##########################**

But when I open by recent project&solution shortcut -> it **doesn't work** !

[image]

result...

[image]

**Can someone help or explain please?**

P.S. Window 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3,Build 9600) | Visual Studio Professional 2015

Comment: Duplicate of [this superuser.com question](http://superuser.com/questions/482368/make-jumplist-shortcut-always-run-application-as-administrator).

Comment: not all duplicate sir !

Comment: Yet another and somewhat less convoluted solution to this problem can be found at http://superuser.com/q/583682/51005

Comment: Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 => https://stackoverflow.com/a/42724159/2008111

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add string value to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\` with name of full path to **devenv.exe** and value `RUNASADMIN`.

For my system path was: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`.

And this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe` for solve this problem.

You can do it in **regedit** or use console command (run with admin right's):

for Visual Studio IDE

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /t REG_SZ /d RUNASADMIN
```

for **Visual Studio Version Selector**  ( *Recomment* *by TooN DinDarkDevil* )

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" /t REG_SZ /d RUNASADMIN
```

Here how it should look in registry editor after key adding:
[image: regedit windows after key adding]

After that all projects will be open with admin rights.

It worked for me on Window 8.1 Pro 64-bit | Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

> **Additional information.** *TooN DinDarkDevil*
>
> *"Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector"* when your window have installed multi version of *"Visual Studio"* .Visual Studio Project&Solution default openning is *"Visual Studio Version Selector"*.
>
> This work for me now (include recent shortcut) .

[image]

result..

1. Open by pin of *"Visual Studio 2015"* ( **work** )
   [image]

2. Open by recent of *"Visual Studio 2015"* ( **work** )
[image]

3. Open by pin of *"Visual Studio Version Selector"* ( **work** )
[image]

4. Open by recent of *"Visual Studio Version Selector"* ( **work** )
[image]

P.S. try it your self !!

Comment: Thank you! for your suggest. Cause your suggest then i founded answer of my problem.

Comment: Then will you approve my edit request. I will give you to my answer ( you will get reward ).

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot for adding info, it's was also useful for me.

Comment: @ToonDinDarkDevil from your screenshot of **regedit** l saw that you've added to registry `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` but not `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` may be that's the reason why it's not worked for you with Visual Studio pin?

Comment: This works in Windows 10 also, where the troubleshoot compatibility answer does not (when right clicking on devenv.exe in Windows 10, there is no "Troubleshoot compatibility" option).  P.S.  how the F*** did you figure this out?  :)

Comment: For me, on Windows 10, the "Troubleshoot compatibility" option worked just fine, plus it was not so much work.

Comment: It works for me on Windows 10, vstudio 2019, although I did it through the "Troubleshoot compatibility" option, with the same result. Good to have this answer, and know what is happening "under water".

Answer (score 40):

I ran the troubleshoot compatibility option.

**Step 1:** Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE. Right click on devenv.exe and select "Troubleshoot compatibility"
**Step 2:** Select "This program requires additional permissions"
**Step 3:** Test and click on next.

Everything will be working smoothly now.

**Note:** Don't forget to save the settings.

[image]

Comment: Much simpler than the accepted answer, and it works very well!

Comment: This worked for me, and much simpler than managing registry changes. Thanks!

Comment: This worked nicely for me on both VS 2015 and VS 2017. The path for 2017 follows a different template than earlier versions, but he process is the same. The 2017 path is something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE.

Comment: this works, just to add the new path for VS2017 pro is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE

Comment: Compared with the accepted answer, this really works for me.

Comment: Yep, this is the simplest answer which works

Comment: Worked on VS 2022 also (Windows 10).  This should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 11):

You can force devenv.exe to *always* run as administrator using the compatibility checker wizard.

Open explorer and go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE. Right click on devenv.exe and select "Troubleshoot compatibility":

[image]

On the first page of the wizard, select "Troubleshoot program". Check "The program requires additional permissions":

[image]

Click Next, then test the program and go next to save the settings.

From now on, every time Windows runs devenv.exe (Visual Studio), it will run it as admin and you will get a UAC prompt. I tested this from the jump list and it worked as expected.

To undo this, just go through the wizard again and uncheck the "...additional permissions" checkbox.

Comment: Sorry! but not working for my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm (VS 2019 and 2022); thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For **win10** and **Visual Studio 2017**
 
You have to add a string key to registry.

Run **Command Prompt** as **Admin** and then run the following command:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /t REG_SZ /d RUNASADMIN
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i ran the "toubleshoot compatibity" option over the devenv.exe and that fix this issues to me. My UAC configuration setting is the default.Same windows version

Comment: Sorry! but not working for my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below to registry changes, update the path to vslauncher appropriately. It will add menu option `Run as administrator` to the solution files. Then you can right click a solution file to open it using elevated Visual Studio. But this won't work with solutions pinned to taskbar.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\Shell\runas\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\MSEnv\\VSLauncher.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Adding screenshot (this is with Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10):
[image: 'Run as administrator' option on solution files]

Comment: Sorry! but not working for my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What's happening when you add the registry entries?

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Right click on the Visual Studio 2017/2019 icon in your task bar
3. Right click on Visual Studio 2017/2019 and click Properties
4. Click open File Location button
5. Right-click devenv.exe file in that folder appears
6. Select Troubleshoot compatibility
7. Select Troubleshoot program
8. Select The program requires additional permissions
9. Click Test the program and wait for the program to launch
10. Then click Next button
11. Select Yes, save these settings for this program
12. Click Close
13. Reopen your project from recent list