# Make Visual Studio 2019 Always Run as Administrator from Start Bar Recent Solutions List

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

Prior to the upgrade, Visual Studio 2017 would always run as Administrator.  I did not think much of this, but now that it is gone it is causing me problems.

**The primary one is that it will not load my projects that use my local instance of IIS.**

I usually launch Visual Studio from my start bar.  Right now this goes like this:

1. Right click on the icon on the start bar and select my solution.
2. It loads and then I realize that the main project did not load.
3. Close visual studio, open as admin
4. Pick my solution and then it loads.

I would really like to only have to do #1 above.  **Is there someway I can edit the shortcut on the start bar to have it always launch as Administrator?**

Comment: Right Click on the Startbar icon, right click again on the Visual Studio menu, choose Properties, then Advanced, and here the Run as Administrator checkbox is waiting for a mark

Comment: ctrl-shift-click will launch in admin mode. Also works from the search box.

Comment: @Steve - I did not know about that setting!  But unfortunately it is already checked.  I tried again after I saw it, and it still only loads correctly when I right click on the icon and then select "run as administrator".  Sounds like something may be wrong with my install....

Comment: @Steve - Must have something to do with selecting the project from the list of options.  If I just run (without selecting a project), then it is administrator.

Comment: Just to offer a troubleshooting step, try deleting the existing taskbar shortcut and recreate it, and then set it to always run as admin, and then see if it works as expected.

Comment: I get same behavior as @Steve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2017 / VS 2019 Run As Admin from Recent solutions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723232/vs2017-vs-2019-run-as-admin-from-recent-solutions-list)

Answer (score 37):

Turns out that Visual Studio uses different permissions when you click on the list of shortcut options it offers in the start menu.  (IE to load a recent solution directly.)

Selecting the Properties->Advanced->"Run as Administrator" did not cause these to run as administrator.

But this did it:

- Find `devenv.exe` (Visual Studio's executable)
- Right Click on it and select "Troubleshoot Compatibility".
- On the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter window, click on Troubleshoot Program
- Check that the program requires additional permissions and click Next
- On the next window, click on Test the program… and VS will open as administrator
- Click next and then click on Yes, save these settings for this program

Now Visual Studio will ALWAYS run as administrator.

(Taken from: https://ppolyzos.com/2017/08/08/always-run-visual-studio-as-administrator/)

Comment: Works for windows 11 as well!